# longtable rows sometime overlaps footer text, how to fix longtable break before footer starts?

Tags: header-footer, longtable

I've a longtable which on some pages merge with footer text. Is there any way to break it before footer line?

Comment: See page 9 in the manual. Just put a `\pagebreak` in front of the row. Such  manual layout should be the last thing you do with the document. i.e. wait until the last proofreading.

Comment: The problem is that the rows are so large that either they run too far or not far enough.  I wonder if \raggedbottom would help?